# Центрировать элемент на странице (модальное окно)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Нашел такой вариант выравнивания элемента по центру страницы.

```
.class {
margin: -120px -127px;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 200px;
}
```

По сути `margin: -120px -127px;` и управляет выравниванием по центру (т.е. минус ширина и минус высота элемента, который центрируется), но проблема в том, что высота элемента каждый раз меняется, соответственно для `margin-top`, который сейчас равен `-120px`, придется каждый раз менять значение.

Как выровнять окно по центру страницы?
Как это сделано в `jQueryUI dialog()`?
* варианты с CSS либо jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то можно это сделать с помощью FlexBox

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/clouds_sun_sunset_colors_height_air_sky_48024_1920x1080.jpg");
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.modal .modal_content {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal_content"></div>
</div>
```

Про FlexBox: на [русском](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/) и [английском](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Поддержка FlexBox [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Answer (score 1):

Также можно центрировать так

Поддержка - http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #00f;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="popup"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

традиционный вариант центрирования

```
 position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
```

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.demo {
  -webkit-animation: test 5s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: test 5s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation: test 5s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: test 5s ease-in-out infinite;
  background: red;
}
@keyframes test {
  0% {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px
  }
  17% {
    height: 150px;
    width: 100px
  }
  34% {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px
  }
  51% {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px
  }
  68% {
    height: 10px;
    width: 200px
  }
  85% {
    height: 200px;
    width: 5px
  }
  100% {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes test {
  0% {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px
  }
  17% {
    height: 150px;
    width: 100px
  }
  34% {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px
  }
  51% {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px
  }
  68% {
    height: 10px;
    width: 200px
  }
  85% {
    height: 200px;
    width: 5px
  }
  100% {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"></div>
```

класс `demo` в рабочем примере добавлен исключительно для демонстрации устойчивого центрирования при любых изменениях высоты и ширины